# parse the string safely so that the split must not fail or if fails it returns 0 atleast

Tags: javascript

How to reduce the parse of this var a into safe way so that if the var a do not return or fail.

```
  var a = "<span style='color:green;'>Speed (NORMAL): 3.36 MB/s</span>";
  a = a.split('>');
  a = a[1].split(' ');
  console.log(a[2]);
```

Outputs:

```
3.36 but its not safe parse cause the a could be empty or null or undefined
```

**Goal is:**

read the value only as: `3.36`

if the  is empty or a is undefined/null etc it should give: `0`

Comment: `parseFloat(yourstring)||0`

Comment: Use a regex : `a = (a.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/) || [0])[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression instead :

```
var a = "<span style='color:green;'>Speed (NORMAL): 3.36 MB/s</span>";
a = parseFloat((a.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/) || '0')[0]);
```

`.match()` returns either an array of results or `null`, so, when the regular expression fails :

```
(null || '0')[0] = '0'[0] = "0"
```

Further reading :

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match